# mysql error when installing wso2 paas

Tags: mysql, wso2, openstack, paas

I have downloaded installer of wso2 paas and put all relevant packages into /packs folder.
I installed wso2 paas on same vmware machine and openstack with ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
When I execute `/boot.sh` as root I get the following error with mysql:

```
Creating APIM database: apim_db
Creating a back-up of the file <WSO2_INSTALL_FOLDER>/resources/dbscripts/apim.sql
ERROR 1071 (42000) at line 495: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0):

open the /resources/dbscripts/apim.sql and in line 495 you will find script similar to below,

```
REG_PATH_VALUE VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
```

Note:there may be 2000 or some other value!

Replace **only the numeric** value with 750 like below,

```
REG_PATH_VALUE VARCHAR(750) NOT NULL,
```

Hope it helps!

**Note:repeat the process if you had same error!**